# Valgrind throwing error on fresh cocoa app on Mac Sierra

Tags: macos, valgrind

I'm new to Valgrind and want to learn to use it on OSX (version 10.12.5 (16F73)). I installed it, created a fresh cocoa app in xcode and simply used the following command in the terminal.

```
valgrind --leak-check=full "blaattest.app"
```

This is showing me the following error and I have no idea how to continue from here. Is there anyone who has seen this before and/or knows how to solve this?

```
==20458== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20458== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20458== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20458== Command: blaattest.app/Contents/MacOS/blaattest
==20458== 
--20458-- run: /usr/bin/dsymutil "blaattest.app/Contents/MacOS/blaattest"
==20458== Syscall param msg->desc.port.name points to uninitialised byte(s)
==20458==    at 0x103C7434A: mach_msg_trap (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x103C73796: mach_msg (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x103C6D485: task_set_special_port (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x103E0910E: _os_trace_create_debug_control_port (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x103E09458: _libtrace_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x100BFB9DF: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x10001BA1A: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==20458==    by 0x10001BC1D: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==20458==    by 0x1000174A9: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==20458==    by 0x100017440: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==20458==    by 0x100016523: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==20458==    by 0x1000165B8: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==20458==  Address 0x10488d62c is on thread 1's stack
==20458==  in frame #2, created by task_set_special_port (???:)
==20458== 
--20458-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option
--20458-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 2 times)
--20458-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 4 times)
UNKNOWN workq_ops option 128
==20458== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x103a60b50.
==20458==    at 0x103A60B50: _dispatch_kq_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x103A5E8FB: _dispatch_client_callout (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x103A5E8B8: dispatch_once_f (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x103A60A90: _dispatch_kq_update (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x103A620CD: _dispatch_kevent_resume (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x103A6203D: _dispatch_source_kevent_resume (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x103A61E85: _dispatch_source_kevent_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x103A71651: _dispatch_queue_resume_finalize_activation (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x103DB13C0: _notify_lib_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x103DB19AB: notify_register_dispatch (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==20458==    by 0x102A108F6: __96-[_CFXPreferences(SourceAdditions) withSourceForIdentifier:user:byHost:container:cloud:perform:]_block_invoke_2 (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==20458==    by 0x103A5E8FB: _dispatch_client_callout (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==20458== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==20458== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==20458== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==20458==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==20458==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==20458== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==20458==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==20458==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==20458== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==20458== probably kill your program.
```

Comment: I think you need to start the executable inside the .app bundle. The .app bundle is just a directory which valgrind does not know what to do with it. Try `blaattest.app/Contents/MacOS/yourexecutable`. However note that valgrind on macOS is not super stable or really supported. It may still fail on you miserably.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch trying it on the executable inside the Contents/MacOS will simply say "command not found".

Comment: I have an identical issue with any Qt based app that I run. I assume macOS 10.12 is not properly supported, just as it was with valgrind 3.12 before.